# looking for efficient algorithm (non-trivial)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

The problem "specification":

*It's Christmas! You have to buy presents!*

You have a set of already existing bundles of toys, and the corresponding price of the bundle:

```
1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 => 58
0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 => 27
1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 => 46
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 => 73
...
```

Where a `1` indicates that the toy is in the bundle, and a `0` that it is not.

Now, Santa Claus promo is coming and a leftover bundle `X` is offered to you at a "special promo price". We will say `X` is a *bad* deal if there exists another bundle `Y` so that:

*Edit: to make it easier, I dropped condition 3 but changed condition 1 from "subset" into "strict subset"*

1. `X` is a *strict* subset of `Y`
2. `X` is more expensive than `Y`

The objective is to implement a function *`bool isBadSubset(X)`* which finds out efficiently whether `X` is good or not.

Given that there are millions of bundles, comparing it to each one is obviously not feasible. Moreover, you can take the assumption that in the existing collection of bundles, a subset of toys is always cheaper than a superset.

Tips:

- comparing whether a set is a subset or not of another set is easy
- one may limit the comparisons to set which are both *containing at least `N` more toys* and *cheaper*. However, the list might still be big.
- something in the direction of a sieve would be good
- you don't need to know *which* bundle is better ...just that there exists one which is better

The challenge: is it possible to achieve this in constant time? (independent of the amount of bundles presently in the collection) ...or at least in log(n)?

Comment: for the "close" voters. Please state why.

Comment: No, it isn't possible to achieve this in constant time, since even examining the input X will take more than that.

Comment: @arnaud: (1) should not the function be called `bool isGoodDeal(X)`? (2) what do you mean by constant time - independent of what?

Comment: @interjay: by constant time I mean independent of the amount of vectors obviously, not length of the vector

Comment: @arnaud: But the number of vectors is dependent on the length of the vector (it can be no more than 2^L)

Comment: @Jiri: (1) `isGoodDeal == !isBadDeal`, I find it personally more straightforward to prove that a candidate is bad than the opposite. (2) previous comment

Comment: @interjay: but there is a big difference between 100 and 2^100

Comment: how many different toys are there? Is it a small constant amount?

Comment: Yeah ...few hundreds at most.

Comment: @arnaud: There is a difference between N and 2^N, but neither one is constant. Any solution you find will be `Omega(T)` and `Omega(logB)` where T is the number of toys and B is the number of bundles.

Comment: @interjay: of course any solution will be proportional to the length of the vector. But as I said, this does not even matter. Comparing the few hundred elements in a vector is peanuts and is considered a constant operation. What has to be avoided is comparing gazillions of vectors! Since the amount of vectors can be very high, up to 2^k! And perhaps this can be achieved by some smart sieve / data structure / bit-packing / algorithm / whatever.

Comment: The key to solving this correctly is to use the analog of a binary search tree, but working on partial orders. Since the value of a bundle is an increasing function of the bundle, you don't even have to take it into account, except when inserting. Unfortunately, I know no such structure. You may try to ask http://cs.stackexchange.com about what such data structures exist.

Comment: Please tell us where you got this question, which seem just to be copied-and-pasted. Homework? Interview question? Something else?

Comment: @starblue: Homework? Interview? ...wow, this would be quite a harsh question! It is not. It is a simplification of a problem I face in a real-life application. I just presented it in a fancier way to make it more easily understandable since the original context is quite complicated.

Comment: So what's the real-life problem about?

Comment: @starblue: ...As I said, it's a bit complicated ...and irrelevant. I fear going down this path would just confuse the reader and trigger undesired off-topic discussions. However, we can gladly discuss it per mail if you want.

Comment: It looks like your problem is equivalent to the general K-way set intersection problem. Google "set intersection algorithm" or somesuch.

Comment: Isn't criteria 3 redundant to #1?

Comment: @AShelly: nope, you can have #1 without #3 (identical bundle for instance), and also #3 without #1 (more toys but not a sub/superset)

Comment: Is it a sparse matrix? In other words, what are the relative sizes of the number of toys, number of bundles, and number of toys in a bundle?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to find some relevant literature on a quick search, and it seems that in the general case your problem is not easy.

[Charikar, Indyk and Panigrahy (2002)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.110.1049&rep=rep1&type=pdf) study the subset query problem: given a set P of N subsets of some universe U of m elements, and a query set Q, is there a set in P that is a superset of Q ? They present two algorithms which trade of storage space for query speed.  In order to achieve O(N/k) query time they need to increase space usage by a factor exponential in the square root of k.

[Bevc and Sannik (2010)](http://osebje.famnit.upr.si/~savnik/papers/iti09.pdf) describe a simple trie-based data structure for subset queries with no analysis of query speed, but it seems clear that it is worst-case linear in the number N of stored sets.

Answer (score 1):

Asking for a solution in O(1) is unrealistic, I think. The only solution I could think of would be generating a full list of bundles and for each indicating whether it is a good one or not... I doubt this is what you are asking for.

A simple binary search might prove interesting though, not even going down into the details of which toys are concerned, we can simply index on the price and the number of items. Our item is a bad bundle if there exists another with a **lower** price and a **higher** number of items.

We can therefore define a key `(price, nb items)` and order them efficiently. The search will be `O(n log n)`, and then the inclusion tests on the subset will still be linear.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the amount of toys, n, is constant and small, i.e. you have the set {toy_0, .. toy_n-1}.

Then you can have an array `Set[n] bundleContainingToy`, and if bundle x contain toy_i, then you save x in set bundleContainingToy[i].

If you get a new bundle 1 0 0 1 0 1 you have only have to compute the intersection bundleContainingToy[0], bundleContainingToy[3] and bundleContainingToy[5]. If intersection is O(1) (which you can probably assume, since you said that checking the subset property is) then you can do this check in O(1) too, since n is a constant (and small).

Is this the sieve you were looking for? The rest of your computation is only dependent on the number of bundles that contain toy_0, toy_3 and toy_5.

Comment: Computing intersection is obviously not O(1) since any set `bundleContainingToy[i]` will contain gazillions of bundles, up to 2^(n-1)!

Comment: No, bundleContainingToy[i] will only contain the good bundles, not any bundle.

Comment: `(1 1 0 0 0 0), (1 0 1 0 0 0), (1 1 1 0 0 0) and (1 ...)` are `2^(n-1)` equally good bundles that could be in `bundleContainingToy[0]` ...or did I miss something?

Comment: Hm, okay, it depends on your situation how many good bundles you can have. In a bad case, still a lot...

Comment: @arnaud: wouldn't 110000 be a bad bundle because of 111000?

Comment: 110000 may cost 28, and 111000 may cost 35. Both are still good bundles. A bad bundle would be 110000 that costs 36.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3337/discussion-between-arnaud-and-daveball-aka-user750378)

Comment: Hm, having arbitrary subsets with costs is quite general, it feels to me that you could reduce some np-hard problem to it. Do you know of an algorithm polynomial in n (as opposed to constant time)?

Comment: Well, linear time: just compare it to all bundles. But that's way too expensive for our application.

Comment: Yes, linear in 2^n, n being the number of toys. Looks np-complete to me ;)

Comment: @DaveBall, NP-completeness is judged based on the length of the input. In this case, the linear solution is actually linear in the size of the input, so it's certainly not NP-complete.

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is that the lookup part should be `O(1)`, you could first construct a map:

```
map = {}
for (bundle, price) in bundles:
  for subset in subsets(bundle): #including bundle
    if map.contains(bundle)
      map[bundle] = min(map[bundle],price)
    else
      map[bundle] = price
```

Now to check if it's a bad deal:

```
  def isBadDeal(bundle,price)
    return map[bundle] < price
```

Comment: ...please read the original question again. Your suggestion does not satisfy the criteria of a bad deal. If it were just a map lookup, I wouldn't have made a post out of it ;)

Comment: You can turn any problem into a map lookup. y=f(x) => y=f[x]. The lookup is O(1), but creating the array is O(n). Your question said didn't specify which part of the algorithm that was time critical. Since you need to read in the bundles, it is already O(n), but if we already have them, we can already also have populated the map, and can thus do isBadDeal in O(1)

Comment: the point is not to lookup a bundle!!! The point is to know if there exists a *superset* (with at least `N` more elements) which is cheaper! Of course you could then do `2^k` lookups, but this is even more pointless than traversing the list of bundles directly.

Comment: My solutions does exactly that. map[bundle] gives you the price of a superset of a bundle. Look at how map is constructed. I simply transform your problem from `any superset(bundle) in bundles` to `bundle in subsets(bundles)`. If map contains bundle, then there exists a superset of bundle in bundles, because I have added all subsets of all bundles to map.

Comment: You suggest that given a vector with `k` ones, we should add the `2^k` subsets to the map. This would simply blow up memory fairly quickly ...and take a lot of time to build since `2^k` operations are needed per inserted vector.

Comment: Yes indeed, but one requirement was that it had to be `O(1)`, and this is the only solution that does it. An efficient solution would use `2^L` memmory, which could be acceptable if one knows that `L` is small (L being number of different toys. Since `L` isn't given, it's impossible to judge if this is a viable solution (or if any solution is viable actually)

Comment: even if `L` is small, like 30, it would take around 10^9 entries in the map, which already needs more gigas than a commodity machine has. ...but this is just a detail ...I think any approach that needs either 2^k memory and 2^k operations to build is ...how should I put it ...not really optimal.

Comment: In the example, l is 9, which is no problem. Even if l=25 it's still possible to handle it. You always have to look at the parameters you're working with. There are a lot of algorithms that require 2^k space, but they choose small ks to make them fast.

Comment: How often do the set of existing bundles change compared to the frequency of lookups?   An 2^k setup time might be ok if it is only done once.

Answer (score 0):

A bitwise *and* between the bundle and all bundles should identify which bundles contain the bundle subset. This followed by an inequality test will return whether or not there exists a more expensive set containing this subset. If any more expensive are found, then the bundle is a bad deal.

In Python / numpy:

```
import numpy

def bad_deal(bundle, cost):
    return ((bundles & bundle == bundle) * (prices < cost)).any()

# Generate some test data
numpy.random.seed(11)
global bundles, prices
bundles = numpy.random.randint(0,511,(1000000,)) # 000000000 to 111111111 
prices = numpy.random.randint(40,70, (1000000,)) # 40 to 70$
```

A better solution is to keep only bundles less expensive than the cost first, then check if the bundle is present in that subset, which means we have a bad deal:

```
def bad_deal_2(bundle, cost):
    less_exp_bundles = numpy.delete(bundles, numpy.where(prices > cost))
    return (less_exp_bundles & bundle == bundle).any()
```

In this case, the worst scenario is that the bundle is the most expensive item and that all other bundles are supersets of it, which requires checking all bundles. In all other cases we are checking less than the total number of bundles. It is however necessary to check all the prices (but there is less data in this vector than in the bundles vector) so checking prices first makes more sense in order to reduce the number of bundles we need to examine.

Comment: This is still linear in the amount of bundles, so it's not any better than the straightforward solution.

Comment: What is the straightforward solution?

Comment: Comparing to each vector in turn. You may gain some speed compared, but you won't gain on complexity.

Answer (score -1):

the three properties that make a vector a bad deal define a relation. This power-set of all vectors together with that relation define a lattice. In order to decide whether a set X is a bad deal you just need to remember the least elements in that lattice. Basic approach:

You start with an empty database. You read the vectors one-by-one. For each vector you check it against your database to see if it is a bad deal or not. If it is throw it away, otherwise add it to your database. The performance of this approach obviously depends on your data. If, as you said, the number of toys is a small fixed number, then you will probably be lucky.

As mentioned above, constant time is not possible, simply because you might have a super-constant number of elements to track, even if you are smart about how to do it.

Comment: "For each vector you check it (...) to see if it is a bad deal or not.": well, that's the whole point of the question: how? ...I guess I'm missing something. What is your solution? To put it in a database and compare the gazillions of records one after another? ...Well, that's precisely what I want to avoid. Moreover, the initial data is supposed to be "clean", containing no bad deals compared to each other.

Comment: @amaud: He means to check whether a vector is a good deal against what you have in the database. So you would add the first bundle by default to the database. You then look at a second bundle, if it is a bad deal against the (currently one) bundles in the database then you ecan xclude it permanently.